# Bigcommerce - curl - update inventory_level by SKU - status 404

Tags: curl, bigcommerce, command-line-interface

I've been trying to update the inventory_level based on the SKU name, but never been successful, would you be able to help to point which part I did wrong?

```
curl --request PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u "myadminlogin:mykey" -d '{"inventory_level":"25"}' https://mystorehash.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/skus.json?sku=SKU-381D364D
```

Here's the error result:

```
[{"status":404,"message":"The requested resource was not found."}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter based on the SKU you need to include the Product ID for the SKU you are referencing.

```
`/api/v2/products/{product_id}/skus?sku={value}`
```

Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/skus#update-product-sku